# Convert string to boolean array

Tags: c, arrays, string, boolean

I need to convert a string that consists of a million 'zero' or 'one' characters (1039680 characters to be specific) to a boolean array. The way I have it now takes a few seconds for a 300000 character string and that is too long. I need to be able to do the whole milion character conversion in less than a second.

The way I tried to do it was to read a file with one line of (in this trial case) 300000 zeros.

I know my code will act funky for strings that contain stuff other than zeros or ones, but I know that the string will only contain those.

I also looked at `atoi`, but I don't think it would suit my needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1039680

int main ()
{
    int i ;
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    bool boolList[BUFFERSIZE] ;

    // READ FILE WITH A LOT OF ZEROS
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr=fopen("300000zeros.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]",buffer);
    fclose(fptr);

    // CONVERT STRING TO BOOLEAN ARRAY
    for (i=0 ; i<strlen(buffer) ; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == '1') boolList[i] = 1 ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried caching the `strlen()` call before the loop? Maybe your compiler is calculating the length of the string in every iteration.

Comment: Assuming `char` and `bool` are both 1 byte in size, iterate the buffer as a list of dwords and then do `dwordboollist[j] = dwordbuffer[j] & 0x01010101`.

Comment: Or you could just iterate without using the length and stop once you reach a null character.

Comment: @Gopi Avoids the cost of traversing the array a second time.

Comment: @Rufflewind One parse through the array is needed and without using strlen() it can be done

Comment: NOOOOOO REALLY? I replaced strlen(buffer) by length which is just 
"int length = strlen(buffer)" and it is done within the desired second.

Comment: How come this works so much better?

Comment: Because your compiler doesn't optimize the repeated call to `strlen`. Instead of making it just once and replace `i<strlen(buffer)` with the calculated value, `strlen` will be called for every iteration of the for-loop, causing `buffer` to be iterated over 300k times. Rufflewind's solution is still the better one.

Comment: you may need `fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]s",buffer);` and a buffer of size 1039680+1 characters for the string plus NULL termination byte

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you use any compiler optimization options?

Comment: Is this a constant value? Why don't you write down a short Python script to auto-generate a source file with `bool boollist[] = {your values}`? This way you can have it embedded into your program with no runtime impact (load time will be considerably long though).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
char *sptr = buffer;
bool *bptr = boolList;
while (*sptr != '\0')
    *bptr++ = *sptr++ == '1'? 1:0;
```

Comment: Correct. However such "condensed" code should not be given without documentation. It simply isn't cool, at least not as an answer on SO. Also it most likely would not pass any production code review. -1

Answer (score 2):

If the string length is always 1039680 characters like you said then why do you use `strlen(buffer)` in your code? Why don't just loop `BUFFERSIZE` times? And if the string length can be changed somehow then you should cache the length into a variable like others said instead of calling it again and again each loop.

More importantly you haven't included space for the NULL termination byte in the buffer, so when you read exact `BUFFERSIZE` characters, the char array is not a valid NULL terminated string, hence calling strlen on it invokes **undefined behavior**

If you want to read the file as text then you must add one more char to buffer

```
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE + 1];
```

Otherwise, open the file as binary and read the whole 1039680-byte block at once. That'll be much faster

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), BUFFERSIZE, fptr);
```

And then just loop over `BUFFERSIZE` bytes and set it to 0 without a branch

```
for (i = 0 ; i < BUFFERSIZE; i++)
{
    buffer[i] -= '0';
}
```

You don't need another `boolList`, just use `buffer` as `boolList` or change the name to `boolList` and discard the buffer

Comment: This way, is the char buffer cast as a bool buffer?

Comment: Only if `sizeof(char)  == sizeof(bool)` then you can cast like that. Otherwise you need separate arrays, but you can still get a branchless solution like this `boolList[i] = buffer[i] - '1'`. But why don't just use char? Unless you're passing it to some other's interface, char is enough in your case

Comment: This _is_ the right way of solving this answer other than there is no need for the `BUFFERSIZE + 1` in `char buffer[BUFFERSIZE + 1];`  `char buffer[BUFFERSIZE ];` is fine.

Comment: @chux but without +1 `strlen` won't work as expected

Comment: 1) On reading, `buffer` is treated as an array, not a string.  2) `buffer[BUFFERSIZE]` is never set to _anything_, so it does not help as a `'\0'` terminator for a string.  3) `buffer[i] -= '0'` results in an array of  `'\0'` (the null character) and `'\1'`.  That does not make for much of a printable string anyways.

Comment: @chux I've mistaken about the `[set]` specifier. The OP's calling `strlen` on buffer, so it should be a NULL terminated string if using that way